# ActionBar icons doesn't change on landscape

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I want to show one icon and 2 items in CollapseActionView on portrait and all 3 icons on landscape mode in ActionBar. I have created two seperate files menu.xml and put it in port and land folders. My port/menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/maps"
        android:icon="@drawable/checkin"
        android:title="@string/maps"
        yourapp:showAsAction="collapseActionView" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/sort_by"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_content_sort"
        android:title="@string/sort_by"
        yourapp:showAsAction="collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

land/menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/maps"
        android:icon="@drawable/checkin"
        android:title="@string/maps"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/sort_by"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_content_sort"
        android:title="@string/sort_by"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

For some reason ActionBar always shows according to port/menu.xml despite device's orientation. What's wrong?

Comment: Use only one xml and use showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" in second and third item.

Comment: Now I get all the icons to show up in both orientations

Answer (score 1):

Try to invalidate the menu and recreate using the land/port menu.xml:

```
boolean isLandscape = false;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    if(isLandscape) {
        inflater.inflate(R.land.menu, menu);
    else
        inflater.inflate(R.port.menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);

    if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        isLandscape = true;
    else if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        isLandscape = false;

    invalidateOptionsMenu()
}
```

Comment: it crashes when I rotate device

Answer (score 0):

After additional researches I have figured out by myself. I just needed one menu.xml file and not to define showAsAction. My menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/maps"
        android:icon="@drawable/checkin"
        android:title="@string/maps" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/sort_by"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_content_sort"
        android:title="@string/sort_by"/>
</menu>
```